# I have a string of the name of a variable I want to change

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, binding

This is an over-simplification of what I'm trying to do, but I believe the answer will get me going...

I have several strings bound like so:

```
private string _Box1 = "";
public string Box1
{
    get { return _Box1; }
    set
    {
        _Box1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I have several boxes... Box1, Box2, Box3... etc.
I can change the value of Box1 simply with:  Box1 = "whatever";

How could I iterate through box variable names (not controls) if I have a string with the proper name in a loop...

```
strining boxvariablename = "Box";
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
     boxvariablename += i;
     ChangeVaribleByTheSameNameAsThisString(boxvariablename) = "This new string value"
}
```

Comment: Why you don't simply use a collection like a `List<string>` which you can access via index or if you really need to access them via name use a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Take a look at ItemsControl. Bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of strings, and put an appropriate UI element into its ItemTemplate to show the string item.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario, the solution will vary.
All solutions benefit from having the actual data stored in a collection. You can iterate over this collection to manipulate the data item.

To modify the properties of a class based on their name using an iterative solution is also possible e.g. using a `Dictionary` or using reflection. Since this doesn't seem to be appropriate to solve your problem, I won't show this.

Remarks: your example starts the for-loop at index '1'. To enumerate a collection fro beginning to end, the index must start at '0'. Otherwise you'd skip items. Index is always zero based.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> BoxValues { get; }

  public ViewModel() 
  {
    this.BoxValues = new ObservableCollection<string> 
    {
      "Box1 Value",
      "Box2 Value",
      "Box3 Value"
    }
  }

  private void ManipulateBoxValues()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      this.BoxValues[i] = "This new string value"
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

If the controls that are bound to the data are scattered across the view (not grouped), you can bind to the collection using the indexer:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DatContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding BoxValues[0]}" />
      <TextBox Text="{Binding BoxValues[1]}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding BoxValues[2]}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If the items are grouped together you should use an `ItemsControl` like `ListBox` and define an optional `DataTemplate`.
If the items are of type `string`, you only need to define a `DataTemplate` when you want to enhance the items layout beyond showing the plain text value (e.g. when you need to display text as a `TextBox`). By default the `ItemsControl` will create a `TextBlock` to display the items:

```
<Window xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DatContext>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BoxValues}">

    <!-- Optional. The DataContext of the template is the item itself. -->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding} />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection. Assuming that the code that updates value will be in the same class, under an instance method:

```
string boxVariablePrefix = "Box";
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
     string boxVariableName = boxVariablePrefix + i;
     this.GetType().GetProperty(boxVariableName).SetValue(this, "This new string value", null);
}
```